# How do I find the least b from lcm(a,b) = c?

Tags: algorithm, lcm

I know `a` and `c`. How can I find the least `b` if `lcm(a,b) = c`?

Comment: If b exsits, the least b is c.

Comment: @rsy56640 sorry, not gcd...least common multiple

Comment: Least b should be `c/a`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the least common multiple using [prime factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple#Finding_least_common_multiples_by_prime_factorization). Here, `lcm(a, b)` has to contain all the prime factors of `a` and `b` in their highest multiple they appear in in any of the two numbers.

For example, `8 = 2^3` and `12 = 2^2 * 3`, so `lcm(8, 12) = 2^3 * 3 = 24`.

This can easily be reversed: Find the prime factors of `c` (including their multiplicity), then check which ones already are covered by `a`. `b` has to be the product of the remaining ones.

So if `c = 24 = 2^3 * 3` and `a = 6 = 2 * 3`, then `b` has to be `8 = 2^3`. The `3^1` is already covered by `a`, but `a` only has `2^1`, so `b` has to be `2^3`.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = m*d, b = n*d, d = gcd(a,b), so c = lcm(a,b) = mnd;  
Thus n = c/a. Notice that the less d, the less b.  
so we can traverse the factor d of a, such that gcd(a/d, n) = 1.
the least d is what we need, then b = n*d.
```

Comment: so I have to find d from gcd(a/d, n) = 1? how?

Comment: you should find the factors of a, then traverse factor array to find  the minimal d such that gcd(a/d,n)=1

Answer (score 0):

If `c` is `lcm(a, b)`, `c%a=0`

Then,

```
(gcd(a, c/a) * c) / a
```

gives the answer.

This follows from the fact that `lcm(a,b) * gcd(a,b) = a * b`

Also, `gcd(a,b)` is easily implemented through euclid's algo, which solves your problem in logarithmic-complexity.

Comment: This does not seem right. What with `lcm(6,b)=24`? `gcd(6,24/6)=2`, so `b=24`? But `b=8` is also valid, and smaller.

Comment: O, thats true. Missed the case.